# Android: Can a 3rd party application use AT commands to auto answer phone call...?

Tags: android, at-command, phone-call

I need to develop an auto answering (GSM call) Android application.

I searched internet and learned that 3rd party applications do not have permission "android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE", because of which my application can not auto answer a call.

Then, I read about these AT commands. After reading different links I am still unsure about two things which I want to ask:

1. Can a 3rd party application use these AT commands to auto answer phone call...?
2. Does it require root access?

I think it needs root access (but I need to confirm), because on my unrooted phone I used command

```
"busybox microcom -t 5000 /dev/ttyGS0"
```

but I got

```
"busybox: permission denied"
```

( I tried to root the phone but because of some problem I am unable to root it.)

Since, I don't have any background of working with AT commands,So, before starting to write complete code for AT command, I need to confirm those above two points, to make sure that I 'm going in the right direction.

(I'm confused because, I wrote simple code to get the names of ports but program did not show any output (for my unrooted phone)...)